# Parasing Error: Unexpected Token, I think I added an extra }

Tags: discord.js

Im having problems with my code it says Parsing Error Unexpected Token Please Help, discord.js code ;-;
Im making an eval command btw so if you help it'd really be appreciated ( it says most of the post is code so Im adding some text pls ignore this - haha guns go brrrrrrrrrr)

```
const { Message } = require('discord.js');
const Client = require('../../classes/Unicron');
const BaseCommand = require('../../classes/BaseCommand');
const Util = require('util');
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

module.exports = class extends BaseCommand {
    constructor() {
        super({
            config: {
                name: 'eval',
                description: 'Only The Owner Can Use This Command!',
                permission: 'Bot Owner',
            },
            options: {
                aliases: [],
                clientPermissions: [],
                cooldown: 3,
                nsfwCommand: false,
                args: true,
                usage: 'eval [js input]',
                donatorOnly: false,
                premiumServer: false,
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Return the exchange rate for one crypto currency in terms of other currencies.
     * @param  {string} fsym
     * @param  {Array<string>} tsyms
     * @param  {Message} message
     */
  async run (client, message, args) {
    if (message.author.id !== 'ownerID') return; {
      let evaled; 
      try {
      evaled = await eval(args.join(' '));
      message.channel.send(inspect(evaled));
      console.log(inspect(evaled));
        }
      catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      message.reply('there was an error during evaluation.');
      }  
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the error's coming from `if (...) return; {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an extra `}` at the end. Also, that `if (message.author.id !== 'ownerID') return;` makes no sense in context.